# Ball rolling down curve simulator

Tags: undergraduate-education, reference-request, undergraduate-research

I am preparing a seminar on mathematical discovery for beginner's students, and one of the topics I plan to cover is the brachistocronic/tautochronic curve. For this purpose, I would like to let the students experiment with various curves connecting two given points P and Q for a while, trying to minimize the time it takes a ball starting at P to arrive at Q.

Since I cannot think of a feasible way to do it physically, I am looking for a suitable piece of simulation software. Ideally, one should be able to draw a curve and then have it simulate a ball rolling along that curve, showing the time it took at the end.

So far, I have been able to find this:

https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Circular-and-Satellite-Motion/Roller-Coaster-Model/Roller-Coaster-Model-Interactive

This is about what I want, but for my purposes, it is too "coarse" with just four adjustable points.
Does anyone know of a piece of software that does this? Since it should be used by the students during class, it would be good if it was freely available online.

Comment: Good question! One thing that came to mind is desmos and their **marbleslides**. (Example link: https://teacher.desmos.com/activitybuilder/custom/58d2e943da79b10e8a73170e ) I have used these in activities where students have to adjust the function so the marbles roll down the curve and "collect the stars." I am not sure if it's possible to modify this to exactly your needs, but I can at least guarantee this kind of thing allows students to modify the function formula and then click a button to set the marble in motion.

Comment: I was also thinking of desmos. Can you write the functions as functions of time, to include the physics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Energy Skate Park](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/energy-skate-park/latest/energy-skate-park_en.html) by PhET seems to come quite close:
[image]

In the "Playground" section you can draw arbitrary curves and add a stopwatch. The simulation has to be manually stopped at the end of the curve and you have to deal with a person (or a dog) skating down the curve, but otherwise it should do everything that you need.

You could also use the "Bumps" setting in [the simulation that you suggested](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Circular-and-Satellite-Motion/Roller-Coaster-Model/Roller-Coaster-Model-Interactive).

Finally, there is [this product](https://www.phywe.de/physik/mechanik/stoff-materialeigenschaften/berg-und-talbahn-fuer-demo-tafel-magn_410_1341/) (german supplier, but maybe "magnetic curve track" yields results for your country as well) to create real curved tracks on any magnetic surface:[image]

Comment: Yes, that is quite exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!
Also, the "hardware" version looks great and should not be hard for me to obtain, as "my country" happens to be Germany. :-)